# Appending values to dictionary items

Tags: python

what i am doing in my program is:

```
1. Reading an input file which has 4 columns(All are strings except first column)
2. Splitting them into 4 fields using split()
3. Making last column values as keys and second column values as values
4. If a key already exists, appending the value to the existing item
```

The sample input file is:

```
66.518706001    00:27:10:2b:93:84       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff       gsdtestopen
72.753800001    00:27:10:2b:93:84       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff       gsdtestopen
90.646014001    00:13:e0:d8:c5:42       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff       alpha_phone
90.646018001    00:13:e0:d8:c5:42       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff       alpha_phone
```

My code is as follows:

```
ssid = dict()
with open("luawrite", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
            hashes = line.split("\t")
            if(hashes[3] != ""):
                    emp = hashes[3]
                    if emp in ssid.keys():
                            ssid[emp].append(hashes[1])
                    else:
                            ssid[emp] = hashes[1]
    print ssid
f.close()
```

The error i am getting while running this code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ssidcategorize.py", line 10, in <module>
ssid[emp].append(hashes[1])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I came to know that i cannot append to strings, but is there no turnaround this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make each value a list instead (or some other multi-value type).

```
else:
    ssid[emp] = [hashes[1]]
```

...

```
    ssid[emp].add(hashes[1])
else:
    ssid[emp] = set([hashes[1]])
```

Comment: Using `defaultdict` with `list` as the default is another option for Justin to investigate.

Comment: I am getting lots of duplicates in list values, how to eliminate duplicate values?

Comment: Use a type that eliminates duplicates.

Comment: @Ignacio NameError: name 'add' is not defined..??

Comment: @JustinCarrey: You should read a little more about [Python's data types](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/).  [Sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) have an `add` method.  [Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) have an `append` method.  Sets will not allow duplicates.  I have linked to various documentation.